# Intellij 2018.1 force push

Tags: git, intellij-idea-2018

According to [Intellij documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-version-control-git.html) there should be a checkbox for enabling the force push "Allow force push" in the Git settings. However, I do not see it in my Intellij, see the screenshot. So, where is it?
[image: Git settings]

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer in the JetBrains forum: [Question thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000573844-Intellij-2018-1-force-push)